# html2pdf php cron doeswork, when run by URL it does

Tags: php, cron, html2pdf

When I run this code from my browser it creates the PDF file just fine. When I run as a cron job, I get the below error. I am sure this is a small configuration, but I am stuck, looking for help/ideas.

Again, I know all the pathing is correct (at least as it relates to serving up the code in the browser).

CODE:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
$Content = stream_get_contents(fopen("$LogURL", "rb"));

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','Letter','en', false, 'ISO-8859-15', array(15, 15, 15, 15)); 
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($Content);
$html2pdf->Output("$FileName.pdf", "F");
```

ERROR:

Warning: fopen(sentlogs/C222P128D2017-08-03.pdf): failed to open stream

Answer (score 0):

The cron job is probably running as a different user than your php service or webserver. Look which user has write permissions for the sentlogs directory. That should be the same user that executes the cron script.

Comment: ok friggin brilliant I didn't think of that let me look into it

Comment: uhg, ok, now I am permissions land that I know little about.is there an easy way to determine which user it runs as when serving a browser url and which it runs as in a cron job?

Comment: Like I said, look at the owner of the sentlogs directory. As it is working from the browser that is probably the correct user. `ls -l` should do it. How did you set up the cronjob?

Comment: OK I tried to chown the directory but I can't figure out what user the cron is running as, so, now I create the directory in the cron which seems to handle all the permissions, and everything works. Thanks for your help.